# How do I connect DevExpress DxUpload control to SQL Server in Blazor Server and use it?

Tags: .net, sql-server, blazor, devexpress, blazor-server-side

How do I connect DevExpress DxUpload control to SQL Server in Blazor Server and use it?

I have been searching online for like 5 days and have come across nothing even remotely close on how to do this.

Here is the basic code that comes from the DxUpload docs.

```
<label>Upload a file:</label>
<div class="upload-container">
    <div style="@(SelectedFilesCount > 0 ? "display: none" : string.Empty)">
        <span class="drop-file-icon mb-3"></span>
        <span class="mb-3">Click the Select Files button to select a file: </span>
    </div>
    <DxUpload Name="myFile"
        UploadMode="@UploadMode.OnButtonClick"
        AllowMultiFileUpload="true"
        UploadUrl="@GetUploadUrl("api/Upload/Upload/")"
        SelectedFilesChanged="@SelectedFilesChanged"
        MaxFileSize="15000000"
        CssClass="@(SelectedFilesCount > 0 ? "w-100" : string.Empty)">
    </DxUpload>
</div>
```

I want to use this as part of an app for work. I know it has to be possible since the non-blazor control works easily.

Comment: [Polite] Ask DevExpress?  It's a paid for library, and support is what you are paying for.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis DxUpload is a DevExpress component for Blazor. I already put in a support ticket and they responded that they don't have a built-in way and I'd need a 3rd-party web api or something else, and forwarded me links to their docs that show nothing about databases. That's why I posted this here.  >8-(

Comment: A DxUpload control is going to agnostic about where the file is saved - that could be on disk, in a storage bucket, to a database ... or anywhere that binary data can be persisted. The [documents](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxUpload) suggest you to create a controller action - in your action you could take care of saving the file in your database -- the "normal" way that binary objects are saved in databases ... whatever that is (!) - but that is a different question. Your language isn't very precise here. DxUpload controls are not "connected to databases".

Comment: Tim. Most of us who answer questions here have our own libraries, and are no  DevExpress experts. If DevExpress say no then your probably going to have to accept that you need another way.  "I have been searching online for like 5 days and have come across nothing even remotely close" is probably telling you something.